# Comparing Composition of Samples

Tags: anova, proportion, ecology, anosim

I have data on the composition of two different types of animal droppings. There are 15 observations of Animal 1 and 40 observations of Animal 2. I have the makeup of each dropping broken up into about 40 different possible components. The data is something like:

- Animal Type 1, Observation $N_1$: 10% Component 1, 30% Component 2, 0%
  Component 3,... 15% Component 40
- Animal Type 2, Observation $N_2$: 40% Component 1, 0% Component 2, 20%
  Component 3,... 15% Component 40

I want to see if there is any significant difference between the two types of droppings.

**Problems I'm having:**

- This falls outside of the range of most of the parametric tests I know. I don't want to run-- and correct for a correct familywise error rate-- tons $\chi^2$ tests.
- I have so many different components that I don't think building any kind of multinomial model will work. I don't think all the parameters will even be identifiable.
- I cannot reduce the dimensionality of my problem in a easy way. My collaborator is unable to narrow down which components they think are important for finding a difference between the two types of droppings.
- From the preliminary data analysis I've done, I would be really surprised if there actually is a different between the two types of pellets. The researcher I'm working with is not very knowledgable about statistics, and they're so assured that they have great, conclusive results that I doubt they'll believe anything without p-values and significant tests, even if the method isn't 100% appropriate..

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried some clustering techniques to see if my samples will regroup together. I think this worked pretty well, but I don't think this is a strong way to demonstrate a null result.

**What I'm going to try next:**

It seems this type of data frequently comes up ecology. It looks like Analysis of Similarities ([ANOSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_similarities)) is a good tool for what I want to do. Is anyone familiar with any other tools that may be helpful in addition to, or instead of, ANOSIM?